# -1 returning error in cube root calculator

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here's my cube root calculator:

```
cube = int(input('Input an integer: '))
for guess in range(abs(cube + 1)):
    if guess ** 3 >= abs(cube):
        break
if guess ** 3 != abs(cube):
    print(str(cube) + ' is not a perfect cube.')
else:
    if cube < 0:
        guess = - guess
    print('Cube root of ' + str(cube) + ' is ' + str(guess))
```

It returns following error on entering `-1` as input:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/ABC.py", line 5, in <module>
    if guess ** 3 != abs(cube):
NameError: name 'guess' is not defined
```

It prints expected answers for all negative integers expect `-1` and I am unable to find reason for this behavior. It should print `-1` as output and I don't see any reason for defining `guess`when it's being "defined" by `range()`function.

Do you see what I am missing?

Comment: With an input of -1, you are calling `range(0)`, which produces an empty sequence - the body of the `for` loop never executes, so `guess` is never assigned any value.  I think you want `abs(cube) + 1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you put -1 into the function, the for loop never runs. `abs(-1+1)` is 0, so it never runs, therefore guess is never initialized. You may have ment to do `abs(-1) +1`

Answer (score 1):

If `cube == -1`, then `abs(cube + 1) == 0`, and `range(abs(cube + 1))` is empty. So, no iteration happens (because there's nothing to iterate over), and the name `guess` is never created.

Also, `range` is not a function, it's a [class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-range).

Answer (score 1):

You have to indent properly. `guess` is only defined in the scope of the for loop, it is the index of the for loop.

```
cube = int(input('Input an integer: '))
for guess in range(abs(cube + 1)):
    if guess ** 3 >= abs(cube):
        break
if guess ** 3 != abs(cube): # this if is outside the for loop so guess is not defined
    print(str(cube) + ' is not a perfect cube.')
else: # this else-if is outside the foor loop so guess is not defined
    if cube < 0:
        guess = - guess
    print('Cube root of ' + str(cube) + ' is ' + str(guess))
```

I indented those lines below and ran the script, I don't get the error that you got, but I also get `8 is not a perfect cube.` when running the program and I get no output if I input -1 (or any negative number).

```
cube = int(input('Input an integer: '))
for guess in range(abs(cube + 1)):
    if guess ** 3 >= abs(cube):
        break
    if guess ** 3 != abs(cube): # now it is inside the for loop
        print(str(cube) + ' is not a perfect cube.')
    else: # this is also now inside the for loop
        if cube < 0:
            guess = - guess
        print('Cube root of ' + str(cube) + ' is ' + str(guess))
```

My best guess as to what you're trying to do is below. There are probably more elegant ways to write the program, and I know `break` statements are frowned upon for making the logic hard to follow.

```
cube = int(input('Input an integer: '))
for guess in range(abs(cube) + 1):
    # if a perfect cube is found we enter this if statement
    if guess ** 3 == abs(cube):
        # these if and else statements print the appropriate cube depending on if the input is negative or positive
        if cube < 0:
            print('Cube root of ' + str(cube) + ' is ' + str(guess * -1))
            break
        else:
            print('Cube root of ' + str(cube) + ' is ' + str(guess))
            break
    # else if the index cubed is greater than our input, we know it can't be a perfect cube and we should exit the loop.
    elif guess ** 3 > abs(cube):
        # tell the user the input is not a perfect cube
        print(str(cube) + " is not a perfect cube.")
        break
```